# R: Extract alphabetical string from inside of quotation mark in dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe

```
data.frame(string = c('["jewelry","tailor","Jewelry"]', '["apple","banana","orange"]'))
```

I want to create three columns and two rows...
I want to have the dataframe to look like

```
data.frame(string1 = c('jewelry','apple'), string2=c('tailor','banana'), string3=c('jewelry','orange'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `base R`, we could remove the brackets, and use `read.csv` to read the column into a `data.frame`

```
read.csv(text = gsub('\\[|\\]|"', "", df1$string),
    header = FALSE, col.names =  paste0("string", 1:3))
```

-output

```
  string1 string2 string3
1 jewelry  tailor Jewelry
2   apple  banana  orange
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(string = str_remove_all(string, '\\[|\\]|"')) %>% 
   separate_wider_delim(string, delim = ',', 
     names = c("string1", "string2", "string3"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  string1 string2 string3
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1 jewelry tailor  Jewelry
2 apple   banana  orange
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(string = c('["jewelry","tailor","Jewelry"]', 
     '["apple","banana","orange"]'))
```

Answer (score 0):

a optional tidyverse approach if you know the max number of columns before hand and have no gaps that matter in terms of ordering or column assignment (rows with less then 3 columns concerning this example):

```
# dummy data
myDf <- data.frame(string = c('["jewelry","tailor","Jewelry"]', '["apple","banana","orange"]')) 


library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

myDf %>% 
    # select column to split, new column names and regex with capture groups (parts between brakets
    tidyr::extract(string, into = c("a", "b", "c"), regex = '"(\\w*)","(\\w*)","(\\w*)"')

        a      b       c
1 jewelry tailor Jewelry
2   apple banana  orange
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a valid python/json list.

Using reticulate:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1%>%
  rowwise() %>%
  transmute(string=list(reticulate::py_eval(string)))%>%
  unnest_wider(string, names_sep = '')

#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   string1 string2 string3
#>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
#> 1 jewelry tailor  Jewelry
#> 2 apple   banana  orange
```

using `jsonlite`:

```
a <- jsonlite::fromJSON(paste('[', paste(df1$string, collapse = ','), ']'))
setNames(data.frame(a), paste0('string', seq(ncol(a))))

#>   string1 string2 string3
#> 1 jewelry  tailor Jewelry
#> 2   apple  banana  orange
```

or even:

```
d <- do.call(rbind, lapply(df1$string, jsonlite::fromJSON))
setNames(data.frame(d), paste0('string', seq(ncol(d))))

  string1 string2 string3
1 jewelry  tailor Jewelry
2   apple  banana  orange
```

Answer (score 0):

`jsonlite` through a list column and `unnest_wider` :

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(jsonlite)

df <- data.frame(string = c('["jewelry","tailor","Jewelry"]', 
                            '["apple","banana","orange"]')) 
                            
df %>%  
  mutate(string = map(string, ~ parse_json(.x))) %>% 
  unnest_wider(string, names_sep = "")
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   string1 string2 string3
#>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
#> 1 jewelry tailor  Jewelry
#> 2 apple   banana  orange
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>